# Could eidetic memory be related to glial cells?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, memory

I am a [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) physicist so I apologize in advance for my biology ignorance.

I recall from a neuropsychology class I took in college (used *Lezak, Howieson, and Loring*, 4th Edition) that there are several types of [glial cells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glia), at least one of which acts to *prune* neurons in your brain.  I am curious if those with an [eidetic memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eidetic_memory) have fewer or different or altered glial cells?  That is, could the *pruning* done by some glial cells affect long-term memory or brain function but not be operating (or at least in a diminished capacity) in those with an eidetic memory?

I found a somewhat related question but it's not directly tied to this one: [Is an Eidetic Memory (or other unusual forms of memory) less susceptible to anterograde amnesia?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/20369/62377)

**References**
Lezak, M.D., D.B. Howieson, and D.W. Loring *Neuropsychological Assessment*, 4th Edition, Oxford University Press, Inc., New York, New York, 2004.

Comment: Usually we talk about pruning *synapses* rather than *neurons*, and I don't think that's something that has changed. I think your edits have improved things but I don't think you'll get more than a speculative answer.